# what will be the regular expression of highlighted values?

Tags: regex, jmeter

{"id":"mergeresult:68b2a5f3-f22a-40c7-b6d0-728ca3f4ede2:2020-06-25:fd18a85c-a1a8-40ae-859a-465b6b9b13a8","mailMergeId":"1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07"}

This is the response I a m getting from api and I want this 1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07 in my output variable without quotes and also mergeresult:68b2a5f3-f22a-40c7-b6d0-728ca3f4ede2:2020-06-25:fd18a85c-a1a8-40ae-859a-465b6b9b13a8
so basically I want id and mailMergeId value without quotes so that I can pass it into next api request

Comment: Please provide your sample as text (not screenshot), so any potential helper can use it easily via copy+paste, for his own tests & trials.
What exactly is the input: either line one or line two or the whole text with two lines or more lines with additional text?
What exactly is the expected result for each of the two regular expressions?

Comment: Please show what is in the picture as text in your question so that readers who wish to test code against your data can cut and paste. Secondly, you haven't told us the rules being applied to determine what text is to matched.  For example, you might say that, for the first text, that you wish to "match the part of the string that follows `id: "` and ends...".

Comment: {"id":"mergeresult:68b2a5f3-f22a-40c7-b6d0-728ca3f4ede2:2020-06-25:fd18a85c-a1a8-40ae-859a-465b6b9b13a8","mailMergeId":"1636afe5-d103-45d1-8786-d13022d92e07"}

Answer (score 0):

This is for your id of type `8-4-4-4-12`

```
[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}
```